# JavaScript XMLHttpRequest with credentials to ASP.NET API

Tags: javascript, .net, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am trying to do a post request `withCredentials = true`, but I get a `CORS` error on the console after sending the request.

This is the Controller I am trying to reach:

```
[RoutePrefix("Account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController;
```

This is the Action I am trying to reach:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Login")]
public IHttpActionResult Login(LoginDto dto);
```

I have added this line in `WebApiConfig:`

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost", "*", "*"));
```

And here is what I use to do `Post Requests` with `Javascript`

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    if (xhr.withCredentials != undefined) {
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}

function post(url, data) {
    return new Promise(
        function httpPromise (resolve, reject) {
            var request = createCORSRequest("post", url);
            if (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
                request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                request.onloadend = function (progress) {
                    var status = request.status;
                    var result = JSON.parse(request.response || "null");
                    if (status >= 200 && status < 300) resolve(result);
                    else reject(result ? result.Message || result : result);
                };
                request.send(data);
            }
        });
}
```

Below is the Error Message that appears in the console.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:54368/Account/Login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: Can you please share the constructed headers that you are sending with the response from the developer tools? Could help a lot.

Comment: The error message already very explicitly tells you what is missing ... so, go add that response header.

Comment: @CBroe I Did add `request.setRequestHeader(''Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');` when I first saw the problem, but nothing in the result changed.

Comment: @BotondBertalan How am I supposed to check that? (Using chrome)

Comment: Where did you add that? For a specific request method only?

Comment: Developer console -> network tab -> click on your request -> Headers

Comment: @BotondBertalan Thank you for your comment

Comment: you are very welcome @nickzoum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give specify `SupportsCredentials = true` in your `config.EnableCors(…)` call:

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost", "*", "*")
{ SupportsCredentials = true });
```